# Phonegap or nimblekit

Tags: cordova

I want to develop web multi platform apps. I searched on the web and I found Phongap and NimbleKit. So, what's the best?. I also saw that phonegap needs external libraries like sencha touch so, I'd like to know witch are the best too.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

NimbleKit is iOS (iPhone/iPad/iPod Touch) only, so if multi-platform is one of your requirements, NimbleKit would not meet it.

PhoneGap doesn't "need" external libraries like Sencha Touch anymore than a website "needs" one. Mobile frameworks like Sencha Touch, jQuery Mobile and jQTouch *do* make it easier to make an application that behaves well on a touch screen mobile device... but it is not required.

The frameworks do make things easier and nicer in my opinion, but you could always roll your own UI and JavaScript. It would depend on your UI goals what would work best for you.